# Regexp matching all the quoted strings

Tags: regex

I am trying to do a regexp, if possible, that would match all the quoted strings from a text.
An example:

```
ABC released its full midseason schedule today, and it features premiere dates for several new shows, along with one rather surprising timeslot change.</p><p>First of all, ABC's previously reported plans for dramas 'Once Upon A Time,' 'Revenge,' 'Grey's Anatomy,' and 'Scandal' haven't changed.
```

I would like to have as a result:

```
's previously reported plans for dramas ' (not useful but i can manage it)
'Once Upon A Time,'
' '
'Revenge,'
' 'Grey'
'Grey's Anatomy,'
etc
```

So i would basicly need to match twice each quote. If i use a standard regexp i would not have 'Once Upon A Time,' and 'Grey's Anatomy,', for obvious reasons.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: It isn't obvious at all. What have you tried and what language are you using? To write regular expressions, you need to define the logic on how to match a certain set of characters. From the set of output you've provided, there are some strings with 2 single quotes and other with 3. Do you think that regex is human like and could detect that `Grey's Anatomy` should be one string instead of two ? This might be a small start [`'(?!s).*?,'`](http://regex101.com/r/gX9cO8). You could view the problem from another approach, catch the second `<p></p>` and then split by `,`.

Comment: well, sorry about that, by obvious i mean a standard regexp that matches anything between two quotes. The language is PHP/PCRE. I can't split by the <p></p> as this is an example, other texts won't have the p's.

Comment: to be more clear, i would like an regexp, that, given an input string like ' text 1' text 2', 'text 3' would give me at least (i don't mind any extra useless matches) text 1, text 2, text 3. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution in **Perl** that works for the given example. See the [live demo](http://ideone.com/ZqbnY1).

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {

#   \1/ Starting at the beginning of a string or non-word character,
#   \2/ MATCH a single-quote character followed by a character that is
#       *not* a single quote character,
#   \3/ And continue matching one or more times:
#       - a white space character,
#       - a word character,
#       - a comma,
#       - or a single-quote that is followed by a lower-case 's' or 't'.
#   \4/ And END the match on a single quote.
#   \5/ Continue searching for additional matches.

    my @matches = /(?:\A|\W)('[^'](?:\w|\s|,|'(?=[st]\b))+')/g;

#                  \___1___/\__2_/\___________3__________/4/\5/

    print join("\n", @matches), "\n";
}

__END__
 'At the Beginning' ABC released its full midseason schedule today, and it features premiere dates for several new shows, along with one rather surprising timeslot change.</p><p>First of all, ABC's previously reported plans for dramas 'Once Upon A Time,' 'Revenge,' 'Grey's Anatomy,' and 'Scandal' haven't changed.
```

**Expected output:**

```
'At the Beginning'
'Once Upon A Time,'
'Revenge,'
'Grey's Anatomy,'
'Scandal'
```

Comment: thanks! you're regexp works perfectly. I will analyse it so i can learn from it.

Comment: @aciobanu - Glad to hear that my solution met your needs. My solution doesn't exactly fit your question, but I thought I understood what you really wanted: finding quoted expressions that themselves might contain quotes under certain circumstances. The tricky part is distinguishing the outer quotes from the interior quotes. Your question gave me the opportunity to do a little learning myself. :-)